# ElasticSearch Terms no longer working since upgrading to ES 2.x

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

Previously with ES 1.x I could construct my nest query like this:

```
Nest.SearchDescriptor<object> query = new Nest.SearchDescriptor<object>()
    .Type("my_type")
    .Size(Int16.MaxValue)
    .Query(q => q.Terms("my_ID", my_list));
```

Since upgrading Nest (and ES to 2.3.0) though Terms no longer takes 2 parameters, so I figured this is the new way to do it:

```
Nest.SearchDescriptor<object> query = new Nest.SearchDescriptor<object>()
    .Type("my_type")
    .Size(Int16.MaxValue)
    .Query(q => q.Terms(t => t.Name("my_ID").Terms(my_list)));
```

If I look at the json this produces now I see it's just this:

```
{  "size": 32767  }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Ah I've just realized Name is to give the query an alias as it were, query construct should be:     `Nest.SearchDescriptor<object> query = new   Nest.SearchDescriptor<object>()
    .Type("my_type")
    .Size(Int16.MaxValue)
    .Query(q => q.Terms(t => t.Field("my_ID").Terms(my_list)));`

Comment: `Name` is to give the query a name, `Field` is to specify the name of the field on which to run the `terms` query. Take a look at https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/2.x/terms-query-usage.html and https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/2.x/terms-list-query-usage.html for examples of use. If you don't specify a `Field` then the query is considered conditionless and is not serialized as part of the query